# How do I force Windows 10 to install the next feature update?

Tags: windows, windows-update, updates

I have several computers which are running Windows 10 version 1803. According to the [Windows lifecycle fact sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet), this release will lose support 18 months after release, which is only a few months away, so I would like to update to version 1903 now.

In Windows Update, when I click "Check for Updates", it always finishes with the text "You're up to date" and a green check mark. There is also text on the right of the window that says "Stay up to date" with subtext "We're rolling out the latest with exciting new features" and a button "See what's new in the latest update". Ok, great Microsoft, I want the update, where is the button to install it?

One of my computers just yesterday decided to update itself to 1809. I would like to further update it to 1903, but I can't figure out how to do so. The difference is that, on that machine, the text on the right of Windows Update talks about how it recently installed a feature update. Windows Update on that 1809 machine doesn't even mention the next feature update.

How do I force these computers to install the next Windows 10 feature update?

Answer (score 1):

> According to the Windows lifecycle fact sheet, this release will lose support 18 months after release, which is only a few months away, so I would like to update to version 1903 now.

**Windows 10 Version 1903 also has not been released yet.**  I would wait, less than a month, and simply allow 1903 to actually be released.  This way you can download the Upgrade Assistant, and upgrade your system to 1903 the day it is released.

If you really don't want to wait for it to actually be released.  The following procedure must be performed.

> 1. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Insider Program and click the “Get started” button.
> 2. Link your Microsoft account or Azure Active Directory account. This is the email account you used to register for the Windows Insider
>      Program.
> 3. Choose “Just fixes, apps, and drivers” to join the Release Preview ring and get the May 2019 Update.
> 4. Confirm the legal stuff.
> 5. Press “Restart Now” to ensure your PC is now in the Release Preview ring. Without restarting your PC, your PC won’t be fully be joined. A
>      restart is required.
> 6. After rebooting your PC, double-check your Windows Insider Program settings via Settings > Update & Security > Windows Insider Program
>      and make sure it shows “Release Preview” under “What pace do you want
>      to get new builds?”.
> 7. If you go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update and press the “Check for updates” button – your PC should receive the May
>      2019 Update.

Source: [Releasing the May 2019 Update to the Release Preview ring](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/04/08/releasing-the-may-2019-update-to-the-release-preview-ring/)

If you performed this procedure you will be unable to leave the Insider Preview program until 1903 is released to the **Semi-Annual Channel**.

> I want the update, where is the button to install it?

You actually want to install `Windows 10 Version 1809` instead of `Windows 10 Version 1903`.  1809 has already been released.  In order to upgrade to 1809, you need to switch to the `Semi-Annual Channel`.  In order to receive 1903 when it's released, you will have to switch to the `Semi-Annual Channel`, if you are currently on the `Semi-Annual Targeted Channel`.  If you do not switch you will instead receive 1809 once 1903 is released to your currently assigned channel.

> One of my computers just yesterday decided to update itself to 1809. I would like to further update it to 1903, but I can't figure out how to do so.

1903 is only accessible on the Insider Preview Release Preview Channel.  The procedure I outlined is the only method I would recommend, and I don't actually recommend it unless you know that ramifications enrolling into the Insider Preview and assigning your system to the Release Preview Channel

> The difference is that, on that machine, the text on the right of Windows Update talks about how it recently installed a feature update. Windows Update on that 1809 machine doesn't even mention the next feature update.

It has not been released.  1803 is the current feature update in the `Semi-Annual Channel`.  1809 is the current update in the `Semi-Annual Targeted Channel`.  1903 will be released to the Semi-Annual Targeted Channel.  Once it is released, 1709 will be retired, and only 1803 and 1809 will be offered in the Semi-Annual Channel

> How do I force these computers to install the next Windows 10 feature update?

You really should wait until it is released.  **The `May 2019 Update (1903)` will be released in May 2019**

If you have Windows 10 Home you cannot switch to the Semi-Annual Channel.  Windows 10 Version 1803 is supported until November 12th, 2019.

> Are you aware that the number "1903" means 2019 March (3rd month)?

While the version of the update will remain 1903, 1903 will be released in May 2019, it was delayed for numerous reasons.

> Last week, we announced how we are improving the Windows 10 update experience with the Windows 10 May 2019 Update in a blog post from Mike Fortin. As part of that blog post, Mike outlined how we plan to deploy the May 2019 Update to customers. Right now, the May 2019 Update (Build 18362.30) is being rolled out to the Release Preview ring starting with seekers. The May 2019 Update will remain in the Release Preview ring for an increased amount of time in order give us additional time and signals to detect any issues before broader deployment.

Source: [Releasing the May 2019 Update to the Release Preview ring](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/04/08/releasing-the-may-2019-update-to-the-release-preview-ring/#bK4CBQqX4BWc7UE3.97)

> One of the most persistent known issues affecting Windows 10 1903 (April 2019 Update) has been the Green Screen of Death (GSOD) triggered by the anti-cheat software used by some games. As Microsoft is almost ready for the public release of the upcoming Windows 10 19H1 and we have a potential Release Candidate, the company has now updated that this particular bug has been addressed.

Source: [Microsoft Finally Gets Rid of Anti-Cheat GSOD – Upgrade Block to Be Lifted Soon](https://wccftech.com/microsoft-gets-rid-of-windows-10-1903-anti-cheat-gsod/)

**The above article mistakenly calls 1903 the April 2019 Update, the article was submitted, before the update was officially renamed to the May 2019 Update**

> I’m pleased to announce that the Windows 10 May 2019 Update will start to be available next week in the Release Preview Ring for those in the Windows Insider Program. We will begin broader availability in late May for commercial customers, users who choose the new May 2019 Update for their Windows 10 PC via “check for updates,” and customers whose devices are nearing the end of support on a given release.

Source: [Improving the Windows 10 update experience with control, quality and transparency](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/04/04/improving-the-windows-10-update-experience-with-control-quality-and-transparency/#MFMgcp2SbYXB2Qvk.97)