# No light in May 2019 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Just installed microsoft windows update. It seems to be big one as i got information that after rebootig system that new things were installed etc...
Nevertheless going into Personalization in colors i do nt see the Light option as should be there according to that update. Any ideas?

```
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.17763 Compilation 17763
```

Comment: Windows 10 May 2019 Update: officially is referred to as 'Windows 10 version 1903' or by its codename Windows 19H1. Running `winver` should show that (or preceding _version 1809_).

Answer (score 1):

> Just installed Microsoft windows update. It seems to be a big one as I got information that after rebooting the system that new things were installed etc

You installed 1809 instead of 1903.  Unless you have opted to receive Insider Preview builds and select the Release Preview channel 1903 cannot be installed through Windows Update at this time.

> Nevertheless going into Personalization in colors I do not see the Light option as should be there according to that update. Any ideas?

You will have to wait until 1903 is released at the end of the month.  The feature you are looking for is a feature of 1903 instead of 1809.  If you have `10.0.17763` installed that is the `October 2018 Update` instead of the `May 2019 Update`.

> Any ideas?

You are not actually running 1903 based on the Windows 10 build you are using.  You will have to opt to receive Insider Preview builds and select the Release Preview channel in order to upgrade to 1903 today[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1428364/how-do-i-force-windows-10-to-install-the-next-feature-update/1428388#1428388)